# CodeIgniter not moving image to the destination folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem uploading an image file to a destination folder in my CodeIgniter application and it is not working at all. I have referred so many articles and downloaded some working one but they wouldn't work once in my application and I am thinking it might be my `.htaccess` file or what.

When I remove the upload `$this->upload->do_upload('fileupload')` path of the `doUpload` function and remove the if conditional statement, record got inserted in the database successfully even with extracting the name of the uploaded file and inserting it in the database table but once I put the `$this->upload->do_upload('fileupload')`, it will not work, meaning the Codeigniter `do_upload()` is not moving the file.

Please check my code `doUpload()` function :

```
public function doUpload()
        {               
                $config['upload_path'] = './Adverts/';  //Adverts is a folder created in the directory where i have codeigniter application folder
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '100048';
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['fileupload']['name'];

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);                             

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('fileupload'))
                { 
                    $data2 = array(
                              'AdvertCode'=>$this->input->post('advertcode'),
                              'CustomersName'=>$this->input->post('customersname'),
                              'AdvertSubject'=>$this->input->post('advertsubject'),
                              'AdvertMessage'=>$this->input->post('editor1'),
                              'AdvertPhotoName'=>$config['file_name'],
                              'Addedby'=>$this->input->post('addedby')
                            );

                        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data2);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('Added Successfully','Record  successfully added');
                            $this->loadRecord();                     
                }
                else
                {   
                        echo 'Error uploading file';                                                                                                                           
                }
        }
```

Below is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: print the upload error using `$this->upload->display_errors()`, so you can find the issue.

Comment: Try using the absolute path of the folder `./Adverts` for example `/home/username/projects/ci/Adverts`

Comment: The path to the directory where the upload should be placed. The directory must be writable and the path can be absolute or relative. Eg: `upload_path` should be `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Adverts'`

Comment: @Olammie Concept, please check log file for error then tell me exact error !

Comment: @Gulshan why `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should use `FCPATH` for root path.

Comment: Welcome to the community.

Are you sure you are uploading the file correctly. Can you share your client side code used to upload the file? Also make use of logging in code igniter. Open the LOGS folder inside the APPLICATION folder and check for any errors or warning in the today's log file. Also try debugging your code using "log_message('info', 'your message')" to see if the code execution reaches the lines of your code.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you tried stepping through using xDebug, enabling all logging capabilities using error_reporting, checking folder names and permissions?

Comment: @SonuBamniya it depend on project sturcutre. Sometime `FCPATH` doesn't fullfill our requirement for custom project structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you already feel right about your code, try check your directory permission, where you upload files.

may this link help you 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/303593/how-can-i-chmod-777-all-subfolders-of-var-www

this example for ubuntu user:

```
root@server1:~# sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/assets/image
root@server1:~# sudo chmod 775 /var/www/html/assets/image
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for my late response due to my health challenge as i fell ill since after i posted this question and i appreciate the help provided by everyone. I have used the dislay_error() to see what the error message for this code is and the error message says : "The upload path does not appear to be valid." .

I have not tested this on the server(hosting server), i worked on localhost and move to server after i have confirmed everything to be working on my localhost. I have changed the upload_path('Adverts/', 'Adverts', './Adverts/', './Adverts') several times but still  not moving them to the destination folder.

Below image is my folder structure :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Emij.png)

Answer (score 0):

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

use this code